# Asp.Net 5 correct way to access logging config file from Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an mvc 6 application and I am currently implementing logging.  I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to load a logging config file from my Startup.cs class.  Is `Server.MapPath` available, or something similar?

Thanks

Edit -

I am able to get the correct path using the following -

```
var path = appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;
var myLoggerConfig = new FileInfo(path + "\\myLogger.config");
```

Is that the correct way to access a config file the root application?

Comment: Do not put your file under `wwwroot` as it could be served directly by a url...you should have it outside the `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: yeah - I realized that after I posted this.  It has since been moved outside the wwwroot

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from the MusicStore sample https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L23-L33